# Setting up relationships for a pair of records in the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an `items` table and I need to create some in distinct pairs. My schema includes an `equivalent_id`, which stores the ID of a partner if that partner exists.

What is the best way to set up the relationship in the model? It seems odd to say `has_one` or `belongs_to` because neither of the items in the pair are in any conceptual way dominant over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Using `has_one`, you could say `has_one :equivalent, :class_name => "Item"` and it looks readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

One-to-One self-referential and bi-directional association is (surprisingly) a bit more complex that One-to-Many or even Many-to-Many self-referential and bi-directional association.

Just to be clear:

- self-referential: the associated item is an instance of the same class that its owner.
- bi-directional: if an item is the equivalent of another, then the latter is also the equivalent of the first-mentioned.

That means:

```
revolver = Item.create name: 'revolver'
pistol   = Item.create name: 'pistol'

revolver.equivalent = pistol
revolver.equivalent # => pistol
pistol.equivalent   # => revolver
```

In other terms, when you set equivalent_id to an item, the owner' equivalent_id must also be set.

One-to-One association doesn't accept `insert_sql` and `delete_sql` option. So it's a bit less pretty. However, the cleanest way to do this (IMO) is:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :equivalent, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'equivalent_id'

  def add_equivalent(other)
    self.equivalent  = other
    other.equivalent = self
  end

  def remove_equivalent
    equivalent.equivalent = nil
    self.equivalent       = nil 
  end
end
```

This way, you can do:

```
revolver = Item.create name: 'revolver'
pistol   = Item.create name: 'pistol'

revolver.add_equivalent(pistol)
revolver.equivalent # => pistol
pistol.equivalent   # => revolver

pistol.remove_equivalent
pistol.equivalent   # => nil
revolver.equivalent # => nil
```

**edit**:

To be secure, you should clean up the relationship every time you add an equivalent. That means:

```
revolver.equivalent # => pistol
pistol.equivalent   # => revolver

revolver.add_equivalent(gun)
revolver.equivalent # => gun
pistol.equivalent   # => nil
```

You can do that like that:

```
def add_equivalent(other)
  remove_equivalent if equivalent
  ...
end
```

Comment: You could override equivalent= to replace any existing equivalent. Assuming that There Can Be Only One.

Comment: @rkb I would be so happy if it was so simple. I skipped the details in my answer but feel free to try and post. I will for sure up vote for a better answer. Transactions are capricious sometimes (especially when it comes to clearing the existing relationship before creating a new one). Once again, that's the **cleanest** way in my opinion to do it.